# pygame create multiple moving objects

Tags: python, class, object, pygame

I am trying to create a simple game with pygame. Currently I am working on having multiple "star" objects and have them move down the screen. How do I make the class take the "i1" without overwriting it every time the game loops runs?

Class code:

```
class Stars(object): # ok, no way around classes now
    def __init__(self, i, i1):
        self.stars_speed = 2
        self.stars_radius = 5
        #self.stars_n = 5
        self.color = white
        self.i1 = i1
        self.i = i
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, self.color, (self.i, self.i1),self.stars_radius)
        print(self.i1)
        #print(i1)
        if self.i1 < display_height:
            self.i1 = 200
            print ("moving star")
            print(self.i1)
        else:
            self.i1 = 0
            self.i = random.randint(0,display_width)
            print ("respawning star")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you are doing this:

```
if self.i1 < display_height:
    self.i1 = 200
```

This part will make the circle stay at the same place always.
I wrote the following code that does the task you described in the question. Hope it will help you.

```
import pygame
import random

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
radius = 10
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

def stars(x, y, color):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color, [x, y], radius)

def game_loop():
    circle_x = random.randint(radius, display_width - radius)
    circle_y = -radius
    while True:
        circle_y += 5
        if circle_y > display_height + radius:
            circle_y = 0 - radius
            circle_x = random.randint(0, display_width)
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    stars(circle_x, circle_y, white)
    pygame.display.update()

game_loop()
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that I did not understand how to create multiple instances and properly assign variables. I started with your solution and expanded it to fit my needs